# GOLD Parse, how do you actually implement your code?

Tags: gold-parser

I am not quite sure how to implement my the code after generating the skeleton. I didnt use const only, i do have main files and i tried several c(++) versions along with c# and still i dont understand. I dont think any of them can load a file and parse test files (i know gold builder can parse my test files).

The Kessels C skeleton looks complete. Buts not, it uses a struct and members (Token->Reduction->TokenStack) yet when i search TokenStack i cant find a place where it is defined, only used. I feel like i am missing something. I cant find Kessels other code anywhere.

My question is how do i implement my body? (is there another skeleton you prefer), are there any other downloads i overlooked? i tried looking at these downloads but i didnt understand what to do with them. It also looked more like example source code then a template http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/engine/c/index.htm

PS: I wouldnt mind doing a C# implementation, i am better with c(++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the [Calitha C# Engine](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/engine/c-sharp/index.htm). Let me know (by posting a comment to this answer) if you still want an answer, which I can answer using my knowledge of this C# engine.

> My question is how do i implement my body? (is there another skeleton you prefer), are there any other downloads i overlooked?

The Calitha Engine download includes source for the Engine, and a sample program (named "TextCalc") which illustrates using it.